# Who is responsible for calling services using the Coordinator design pattern

Tags: ios, swift, mvp, coordinator-pattern

I have an application using the `MVP-C` design pattern.

My rootViewController is a `UINavigationController` and My home flow renders a `UITabBarController` which has 4 tabs.

The tab bar controller has a `UITabBarControllerDelegate` and using a `tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController)` I am able to call a delegate method on my `HomeFlowCoordinator` that allows me to correctly set the title on the navigation bar for the tab.

I did this under the assumption that the Coordinator owns the navigation bar and as such any changes should be handled by the coordinator and not made by the view controller.

My question is that I now have a requirement to add a `UIBarButtonItem` on some of the tabs. I can still do this in the coordinator, however I am starting to wonder if this is the correct place as I need to assign an action selector to the button, which would mean that logic would also live in the coordinator, potentially meaning any service / provider calls would live in the coordinator.

That doesn't feel correct. Is it correct to pass my `UINavigationController` via `DI` into my presenter or view controller and have each tab modify there nav title and bar button actions?

If that is true, they could also present views, which feels like the coordinator almost becomes redundant?

Comment: The right place to create view is actually in a view (or view controller). To show/hide/delete/add a view should go via presenter because it's presenter responsibility. What I understood from coordinators that it's responsibility is to coordinate between different module e.g. main or details.

Comment: Question title and body dose not relevant.
Can you please update your title :)